# Relay controller versus a Micro Controller - n00b question

Tags: performance

What is the difference of a Relay controller versus a Micro Controller?

I'm looking into Arduino boards and just getting into this stuff wanted to know the difference.

I thought this might be better asked on this forum instead of stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Relay Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) is a switch.
A [Microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) is a simple CPU.